# JS проверка на пустое значение input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Пытаюсь проверить input, на значение value, при наличии в нем строки и без.
Строка (Путь до файла), сразу же подгружается через callback или нажатием кнопки, без ввода каких либо символов в input

```js
function checkPath() {
  var val = $('#gamelocation').val();
  if ($.trim(vall)) {
    $('#actionBtn').show();
    $('#gameBlock').show();

  } else {
    $('#actionBtn').hide();
    $('#gameBlock').hide();
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="gamelocation" />
<div class="btn-group" id="actionBlock">...</div>
<div class="btn-group" id="gameBlock">...</div>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу мгновенно скрывать блоки, если input пустой и отображать, если там есть запись? (Запись добавляется такого плана: "D:\Folder\Folder\")

Comment: Нужно показывать блоки при наличии в `input` любых символов или же только записи такого вида `D:\Folder\Folder\`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то ответ следующий:

Подпишитесь на ввод в `input` вот так:

```
$('#gamelocation').keyup(checkPath);
```

Если нужно отследить изменение значения, то:

```
$('#gamelocation').change(checkPath);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/csbrjd7q/

```js
function checkPath() {
  var val = $('#gamelocation').val();
  if ($.trim(val)) {
    $('#actionBlock').show();
    $('#gameBlock').show();
  } else {
    $('#actionBlock').hide();
    $('#gameBlock').hide();
  }
}

$('#gamelocation').keyup(checkPath);
checkPath(); // check initial value
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="gamelocation" />

<div class="btn-group" id="actionBlock">
  Action block
</div>
<div class="btn-group" id="gameBlock">
  Game block
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас! То, что нужно !

Comment: простите, еще один вопрос, при обновлении страницы, даже если информация попала в input, блоки все равно скрыты, не смогла решить сама, вынуждена обратиться(

Comment: нужно принудительно вызвать обработчик, как в последней строчке кода примера.